# What causes a "Cast to ObjectID failed" error?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am getting this error:

> > Booking validation failed: user: Cast to ObjectID failed for value
>
> ```
> "{
>   "userId": "5c4479b51318a01df4a5a5dc",
>   "username": "imran",
>   "iat": 1548003730,
>   "exp": 1548090130
> }"
> ```
>
> at path "user"

Here is my code:

```
    if (isValidBooking(booking, foundRental)) {
    booking.user = user;
    booking.rental = foundRental;
    foundRental.bookings.push(booking);

    booking.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(422).send(err);//getting error on this line
      }

      foundRental.save();
      User.update(
        { _id: user.id },
        { $push: { bookings: booking } },
        function() {}
      );
      return res.json({ startAt: booking.startAt, endAt: booking.endAt });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your error occurs at the line

```
booking.user = user;
```

Further, I'm guessing that whatever object `booking` is, the property `user` is supposed to be an ObjectId, while in this method you are giving it a full `User` object. Try rewriting that line to:

```
booking.user = user.userId;
```